# Dynamic Database with Azure

Tags: c#, database

I am building a project which has the objective to make automatic the Status Report here in my company.

The Status Report have an official template, but other person possibly can add another one.
My database is Azure, anyone knows if Azure is capable to be dynamic?
I mean, I will have some standards fields and tables in my bd, but its possible to add more, by an application? Not using the Database itself?

Comment: If you can add extra tables and columns to existing databases/tables manually, then you can also do this programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are talking about SQL Azure. There are a couple of approaches you can take irrespective of the database you use.

1. Have extra fields that can hold generic datatypes. Have a separate table that maps these to the ID of the person or company customizing this  status reports.
2. Have a separate table for these custom fields which contains meta data including their data type. Have another table that does mapping of these customfields with the person or company customizing these reports.

Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14463457/allowing-end-users-to-dynamically-add-columns-to-a-table) as well